# Handling duplicate keys in HTTP post response in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, http-post

When I send out an HTTP post to a website I get a response that looks like this on my web debugger

```
payload = 
          {
       'name': 'simpson'
     , 'color': 'red'
     , 'color': 'orange'
     , 'color': 'blue'
     , 'color': 'orange'
       'food' : 'pizza'
         }
```

But in python when i send out the same request and do r.headers I get this response

```
    payload = 
          {
       'name': 'simpson'
     , 'color': 'orange'
       'food' : 'pizza'
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

That format is valid JSON but it contains information that cannot be represented by JSON.

The solution would be to not use JSON but write an encoder that uses a list of pairs (2 value tuples) for the data points.

Update:

```
data = [
   ('name', 'simpson'),
   ('color', 'red'),
   ('color', 'orange'),
   ...
   ('food', 'pizza'),
]
content = "{%s}" % ', '.join("'%s': '%s'" % pair for pair in data)
```

POST content.

Comment: So this is the requests modules fault?? I'm a beginner in python and dont know how to, is there any other way to send out requests and get the full responces

Comment: The service is a little strange. Don't use JSON, it's nobody's fault. Create a string with what you want to send and then POST it.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the way you make the request. Actually, the HTTP response body is always a text that can be interpreted as a JSON or something else depending on what you use to request. Probably your library tries to create a JSON of the given data and fault because such data can't be interpreted as JSON, because it contains several values belonged to the same key. I would recommend you to extract the raw response text and to parse it in a suitable way. For example, you may use `httplib` to request:

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.thehost")
conn.request("POST", "/post/url/you/request", "data1=q&data2=w", {...some hreaders...}
response = conn.getresponse()
body = response.read() # body is the text you need, it's a string
response.close()
conn.close()
```